# How can I get Core Data in a project that did't check the 'use Core Data' option at start up?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

When I created my project, I'm new in iOS development, so I did't check the `use Core Data` option, but now I need to use Core Data in my project and I've already put a lot of work on the project so I can't start all over again. So anyone knows how to get those files like `coredata.xcdatamodeld`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact solution to just adding Core Data to a project without Core Data but instead of using Core Data use SQLite. It can be implemented to your project

Let’s take a look at using SQLite directly.

- Relational Database System
- Potential for cross platform compatibility
- Many early iPhone database examples were written    using SQLite
- Objective-C wrappers such as FMDB are pretty easy to      use

Now at Core Data:

- Can store data in it’s own Binary, or SQLite storage format.
- Can serialize objects – Much higher level than using SQLite
  directly
- Not a RDBMS you could actually just store things directly.